# Incrementally read a file and put in DB. Doesn't give errors, but does not insert data completely or correctly

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to write a file to a database 500 lines at a time so I do not run low on memory by avoiding dealing with very large arrays. For some reason, I am not getting any errors, but I am seeing a very, very small fraction entered into my table.

```
    $ln = intval(shell_exec("wc -l $text_filename_with_path"));
    echo "FILENAME WITH PATH: " . $text_filename_with_path ."\n\n";
    echo "ARRAY LENGTH: " . $ln . "\n\n";

    //pointer is initialized at zero
    $fp = fopen($text_filename_with_path, "r");

    $offset = 0;
    $c = 0;
    while($offset < $ln){

        $row_limit = 500;

        //get a 500 row section of the file
        $chunk = fgets($fp, $row_limit);

        //prepare for `pg_copy_from` by exploding to array
        $chunk = explode("\n", $chunk);

        //each record from the file being read is just one element
        //prepare for three column DB table by adding columns (one
        //unique PK built from UNIX time concat with counter, the 
        //other from a non-unique batch ID)
        array_walk($chunk, 
            function (&$item, $key) use ($datetime, $c)  { 
                $item = time() . $c . $key . "\t" . $datetime . "\t" . $item;
            }
        );     

        //increase offset to in order to move pointer forward
        $offset += $row_limit; 
        //set pointer ahead to new position
        fseek($fp, $offset);
        echo "CURRENT POINTER: " . ftell($fp) . "\n"; //prints out 500, 1000, 1500 as expected

        //insert array directly into DB from array
        pg_copy_from($con, "ops.log_cache_test", $chunk, "\t", "\\NULL");

        //increment to keep PK column unique
        $c++;
    }
```

I am getting as I say a fraction of the contents of the file, and lots of the data looks a bit messed up, eg about have the entries are blank in the part of the array element that gets assigned by `$item` within my `array_walk()` callback. Further it seems that exploding on `\n` is not working properly as lines seem exploded at ununiform positions (ie, log records don't look symmetrical). Have I just made a total mess out of this

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the second parameter for fgets is the length in bytes (not number of rows). [fgets documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

Comment: @iLot Is there anyway to use it to specify a number of lines? I didn't see that in the documentation. Thanks very much.

Comment: Just FYI - you can read files directly from PostgreSQL using Foreign Data Wrappers. That is how I get log files.

Comment: @Jayadevan Can you show what the basic syntax of this would be in an answer. I was looking at it earlier today, but couldn't find any wrappers for just text files. Thanks!

Comment: The process has a few steps. Install the extension/Create a foreign server/Create foreign table. The steps are mentioned here - http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/250-File-FDW-Family-Part-1-file_fdw.html. I load the entire log file as one text field into a table (each line is a record), then search for patterns (errors, for example) and insert into different real tables based on the pattern. You have to think about log file switching, what happens if the file switches before the data is read by the script which reads the file and moves data to various tables and plan accordingly.

Comment: @iLot Is there a way to `fgets` by line? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using fgets properly (2nd parameter isn't the number of rows);

There are two ways I can think of at the moment to solve it:
 1. A loop getting one line at a time, until you've reached your row limit.
code should look something like this (not tested, assuming the end of line char is "\n" and no "\r")

```
<?php
/**Your code and initialization here*/    
while (!feof($file)){
    $counter = 0;
    $buffer = array();
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false && $counter < $row_limit) {
        $line = str_replace("\n", "", $line); // fgets gets the line with the newline char at the end of line.
        $buffer[] = $line;
        $counter++;
    }
    insertRows($rows);

}

function insertRows($rows){
    /** your code here */
}?>
```

2. Assuming the file isn't too big- using file_get_contents();
   code should look something like this (same assumptions)

   ```
   <?php
   /**Your code and initialization here*/    
   $data = file_get_contents($filename);
   if ($data === FALSE )
       echo "Could not get content for file $filename\n";
   $data = explode("\n",$data);
   for ($offset=0;$offset<count($data);$offset+=$row_limit){
       insertRows(array_slice ($rows,$offset,$row_limit));
   }

   function insertRows($rows){
       /** your code here */
   }
   ```

I didn't test it, so I hope it's ok.